Is it possible to level a refrigerator while it is turned on?
I need to level a refrigerator that is slightly tilted backward (the doors close by themselves) and is turned on. I am wondering if it is necessary to turn off the refrigerator to level it, or if I can slightly lift it to adjust the legs, for example, when I hear that the compressor is temporarily not running (when the refrigerator is not making any noise).
Below, I am attaching a preview of a few photos of the level, which indicate the presence of the issue.




perfectly safe to do while it is running

I don't think you can possibly tilt it enough to make a difference when simply leveling it.

@Huesmann Do you mean that I can't negatively affect the fridge's operation by tilting it, or that with such a small tilt that isn't harmful to the fridge, I won't be able to level it?

@SkogensKonung the amount of tilt you are likely to do when leveling is nowhere near the amount of tilt that will affect its operation.

Yes, as long as you don't lay it on its side to do so.
So, if you just tilt it enough the free the feet, or foot, just enough to turn it then fine.

I like enough tilt to insure the door closes when left ajar.

@MadMonty The idea of doors that close automatically might not be the worst. For me, however, for one, it is a bit annoying when putting in a larger amount of items, and for another, I read that it is not good for the fridge when it is not perfectly level (how true that is, I don't know).

Refrigerators made for the real world need only be approximately level.  If the door won't close with a degree or two of incline, a little oil should fix it.
